# When an HC-05 Bluetooth module receives data via wireless does it write it to receive (Rx) pin or transmit (Tx) pin?

Tags: serial, bluetooth

I'm using an HC-05 and I have it successfully wired up to my ATMega328P so that the HC-05 Tx is tied to the ATMega328 Rx and HC-05 Rx is tied to the ATMega328P Tx.

So I'm assuming that the data received on the wireless signal is then written to the HC-05 Tx pin. That sends it to the Rx pin of the ATMega328P (since it is wired as I explained above).

Is that a valid description?

Just trying to untangle this in my mind so I understand that **received** data (via wireless) appears on the Transmit (Tx) pin.  I could almost see that wirelessly received data could be found on Rx pin since it is really data that is received but I think the two are separate.

**Guess About HC-05 Chip and Wireless Data**

I'm guessing that a chip on the HC-05 writes the received data to the serial port (Tx), right? And then data that I want to be sent over the Bluetooth from the HC-05 would be read on the Rx pin which is then converted to wireless and sent by the HC-05?

Answer (score 1):

By a convention, `Tx` is the transmitting line (outgoing), `Rx` is the receiving one (incoming). So when two devices are interconnected the `Tx` of the transmitting device should be connected to `Rx` of the receiving device.

**Update:**
 To make it clear, decouple the HC-05 to the wireless part and to the wired serial. The statement above is true for the serial part. So, whatever is *received* wirelessly, is *transmitted* serially. And vice-versa.